# OAuth Logout endpoint for ADFS 3.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I am not sure how to configure the logout endpoints for ADFS 3.0 OAuth2. Could somebody please point me to any information on this? Code and Token endpoints are working okay. ta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the answer is too late for you, but I was looking for the endpoint today. I found the answer on [this blog](https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/uri-to-signout-from-an-adfs-3-0-server-from-the-browser/):

`https://company.adfs.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://targetapp/logout`

Edit: more information can be found on [Microsoft TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx).